# http to https into subfolder (.htaccess)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I have a Wordpress running on an Apache Server. Now I want to configure the following using .htaccess:

- Force http to https
- Redirect requests from (www.)domain.com to domain.com/domaincom/web

So if a user types: `http://www.domain.com` he will be directed to `https://domain.com/domaincom/web` but in the browser navigation he will see `https://domain.com`.

I already have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/domaincom/web/%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L,R=301]
```

But this does not replace the URL. Can you help me?

Comment: You shall separate the redirect from the rewrite. First you redirect the user to https and in a separate rule you rewrite your url to /domaincom/web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

#Enable https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
# if we are not already on /domain/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domaincom/we [NC]
#Then rewrite any request to /domaincom/web
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domaincom/web/$1 [NC,L]
```

The Second condition is important here to prevent rewrite loop error. otherwise without this condition /domaincom/web keeps rewriting to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Web sites behind load balancers or reverse proxies that support HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO can be fixed by adding the **following code to the wp-config.php file**, above the require_once call:

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';

**OR by plugin**

Add into WordPress plugins folder on your website, then activate it in the Plugins admin

https://gist.github.com/krunalsojitra/b975043933bca9183f57581e45858949

It is working like

http://www.exmaple.com/blog/ **to **  https://www.exmaple.com/blog/

http://www.exmaple.com/ **to **  https://www.exmaple.com/